# DataSync In Mvc4 for Two Different User

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync two database of a sql in mvc4 website?

i have this code to sync it is showing no error but it is not getting executing

```
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Planetskool.Controllers
{
    public class DataSyncViewController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /DataSyncView/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string sqlazureConnectionString = "Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Planetskool-20130901224447;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-20130901224447.mdf";
            string sqllocalConnectionString = "Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Planetskool-20130901224446;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-20130901224446.mdf";

            using (SqlConnection serverCon = new SqlConnection(sqlazureConnectionString))
            using (SqlConnection clientCon = new SqlConnection(sqllocalConnectionString))
            {
                var provider1 = new SqlSyncProvider("scope1", serverCon);
                var provider2 = new SqlSyncProvider("scope1", clientCon);

                prepareServer(provider1);
                prepareClinet(provider2, serverCon);
                SyncOrchestrator sync = new SyncOrchestrator();
                sync.LocalProvider = provider1;
                sync.RemoteProvider = provider2;

                sync.Synchronize();
                return View();

            }}
            private static void prepareServer(SqlSyncProvider provider)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning config = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(connection);

        if (!config.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(provider.ScopeName);
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Author_Master", connection));
            config.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            config.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
            config.Apply();
        }
    }

    private static void prepareClinet(SqlSyncProvider provider, SqlConnection sourceConnection)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning config = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(connection);

        if (!config.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(provider.ScopeName);
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Author_Master", sourceConnection));
            config.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            config.Apply();
        }
    }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your initial catalogs are the same but data files different, is that what you intend?

Comment: @jlew no it was by mistake initial catalogs are also different than also it is not executing

Answer (score 0):

You can enable sync framework tracing in verbose mode to trace the synchronization. Likewise, did you forget to set the sync direction?